# Android Tabs with List View

Tags: android, android-fragments

I followed this tutorial to created a tab activity using fragments:

http://thepseudocoder.wordpress.com/2011/10/04/android-tabs-the-fragment-way/

One of the tabbed activities includes a list view; when you click on an item in the list view, it opens a new activity.  But I want the new activity to still show the tabs that are in the tab activity.  In other words, I want the tabs to show up on all the activities in the application, but I don't know how to make it persistent.

Would someone be able to point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

To make your application persistent, make use of `Inheritance`. create `listView.xml`, `tabactivity.xml` and embed those in `MainActivity.xml` as below:

```
 <LinearLayout ... >
<include layout="@layout/listView" /> // your listview.xml file will be called
<include layout="@layout/tabactivity" />   // your tabactivity.xml file will be called
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: My problem is that the tabs are created dynamically.  I could recreate the tabs in every activity, but that seems inefficient.  Is there some way to replace the fragment that the tab creates with the new fragment activity?  So if the tab creates a fragment of a list view containing restaurants, and I tap on a restaurant to view more info, I would like the tabs to still appear.

Answer (score 0):

You can add your tabview dynamically on every activity start.